# Validating user entry matches mixed case requirements

Tags: validation, powershell, user-input, case-sensitive

I am trying to figure out how to test for mixed case or change the user input to mixed case.

Currently my code consists of:

```
$Type = Read-Host 'Enter MY, OLD, NEWTest, Old_Tests'
```

However, I need to validate that the user entered in the exact case, and if they didn't change the case to the correct case.  I have reviewed so many different questions on here and other websites, but none seem to really talk about validating mixed case in a way I can understand.

1. [Validate User Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127304/validate-user-entry)
2. [Regex to match mixed case words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410634/regex-to-match-mixed-case-words)
3. [Validating String User Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650210/validating-string-user-entry)
4. [How to check if a string is all upper case (lower case) characters?](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-all-upper-case-characters)
5. [Learn Powershell | Achieve More](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/04/using-powershell-parameter-validation-to-make-your-day-easier/)
6. [How To Validate Parameters in PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/04/23/validate-parameters-in-powershell.aspx)
7. [$args in powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/686962-args-in-powershell)

I am not asking anyone to write code for me. I am asking for some sample code that I can gain an understanding on how to validate and change the entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell performs case-insensitive comparisons by default, so to answer the first part of your question you need to do a case-sensitive comparison which is `-ceq`.

```
$Type = Read-Host 'Enter MY, OLD, NEWTest, Old_Tests'
($Type -ceq 'MY' -or  $Type -ceq 'OLD' -or  $Type -ceq 'NEWTest' -or  $Type -ceq 'Old_Tests')
```

Although a simpler solution to that is to use case-sensitive contains -ccontains:

```
('MY', 'OLD', 'NEWTest', 'Old_Tests' -ccontains $Type)
```

Here's one way you might correct the case:

```
$Type = Read-Host 'Enter MY, OLD, NEWTest, Old_Tests'

If ('MY', 'OLD', 'NEWTest', 'Old_Tests'  -cnotcontains $Type){

    If ('MY', 'OLD', 'NEWTest', 'Old_Tests' -contains $Type){
        $TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo

        $Type = Switch ($Type) {
            {$_ -in 'MY','OLD'} { $Type.ToUpper() }
            'NEWTest'           { $Type.Substring(0,4).ToUpper() + $Type.Substring(4,3).ToLower() }
            'Old_Tests'         { $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($Type) }
        }  
    } Else {
        Write-Warning 'You didnt enter one of: MY, OLD, NEWTest, Old_Tests'
    }
}

Write-Output $Type
```

**Explanation:**

First we test if the case is correct for the four permitted words (`-cnotcontains` Case Sensitive Not Contains), if it is we do nothing. If the case is not correct, then we test the text is correct (without caring about case sensitivity `-contains`).

If the text is correct then we use Switch statement to deal with the different scenarios that we want to adapt the case for:

The first switch test matches the first two words and simply uppercases them with the `ToUpper()` string method.

The second switch test uses the string method `SubString` to get a subset of the string starting from the first character (0) and taking 4 characters in length. We uppercase this with ToUpper then we add on the next 3 characters of the string, starting at the 4th character, which we force in to lower case with `ToLower()`.

The final switch test we handle with a .NET method taken from the get-culture cmdlet which allows us to Title Case a string (make the first letter of each word uppercase).

If the inputted text didn't match one of the options we use `write-warning` (may require PowerShell 4 or above, if you don't have this change it to `write-host`) to print a warning to the console.

Finally whatever was entered we send to stdout with `Write-Output`.

Comment: how can I change newtest to NEWTest?

Comment: Sorry Mark, I was tied up with other items yesterday and didn't get a chance to validate your tutelage.  I have tested your solution out and it is still not changing the case to upper or lower. Enter MY, OLD, NEWTest, Old_Tests: newtest
                 Write-Output = newtest

Comment: My solution assumed you wanted to handle the whole string at once, not deal with the individual options. I'll amend my answer to deal with that.

Comment: Awesome blog by the way... I'll be reading multiple of your articles. You explain things in English like I understand.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it! I've revised my answer to deal with the input being any one of the 4 individually entered strings.

Comment: I've got everything working and fixed the issue where I'm trying to convert "old_tests" to "OLD_Tests". I now understand how to handle the uppercase and lowercase of items. I now have working code for more than what you helped me understand.